# Metal got an assertion, failed assertion `sourceLevel(1) must be < [sourceTexture mipmapLevelCount](1).' (lldb)

Tags: metal

When I calling blitEncoder's copy API to perform texture copying, the assertion triggered at copying yuv's u channel texture.

*sourceLevel(1) must be < sourceTexture mipmapLevelCount.' (lldb)*

Both textures have the same midmapLevel 1.

```
blitEncoder.copy(from: srcYTexture, to: dstYTexture)
blitEncoder.copy(from: srcUTexture, to: dstUTexture) <-- triggered here
    // assertion: *sourceLevel(1) must be < [sourceTexture mipmapLevelCount](1).' (lldb)*
blitEncoder.copy(from: srcVTexture, to: dstVTexture)
```

Answer (score 0):

The root causes is size mismatched between source and destination textures.

I am copying YV12 buffer. The dstUTexture/dstVTexture which are converted from RGBA buffer. I forgot to resize the U/V buffer size to 1/4. rgba: 1280x720 -> y:1280x720, u:640x320, v:640x320.

So `blitEncoder.copy(from: texture of 1280x720, to: texture of 640x320)` trigger the assertion. Although the message does not mention that.

Problem is solved when I fixed the size of source UTexture/VTexture.